# Change font awesome icon when clicked button

Tags: html, css, button, toggle

I'm using this code to play/pause background audio.

```html
<div class="music-box">
   <audio id="losAudio" src="images/honcayeu.mp3"></audio>
      <button id="btn_playPause">
         <i class="fa fa-music"></i>
      </button>
</div>
```

```js
var losAudio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
function losAudio_playPause() {
   var isPaused = losAudio.paused;
   losAudio[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
}
document.getElementById("btn_playPause").addEventListener("click",losAudio_playPause);
```

But now i want when clicked on button, the icon will be change to fa-pause icon.
Can tell me a simple solution ? THanks

Comment: hi toan. welcome to stack overflow. you can see this link, it is helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the icon of the button from fa-music to fa-pause when the audio is playing, you can modify your losAudio_playPause function to update the button icon accordingly.

Try This :

```js
var losAudio = document.getElementById("losAudio");
var playPauseButton = document.getElementById("btn_playPause");

function losAudio_playPause() {
    var isPaused = losAudio.paused;
    losAudio[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
    playPauseButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa ' + (isPaused ? 'fa-music' : 'fa-pause') + '"></i>';
}

playPauseButton.addEventListener("click", losAudio_playPause);
```

What this does is it checks whether the audio is currently paused or playing, and sets the button icon to fa-music or fa-pause respectively using a ternary operator. The innerHTML property is then used to update the button's content with the new icon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an action inside your function for that. Try to get the element (add an ID) and change the class of the i element

Comment: Can u tell me detail ? Or can u post the code in here ? Thanks

Comment: It has been done in the other post ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `classList`, `add()` and `remove()`:

```js
let pause = true;

document.getElementById("btn_playPause").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let icon = document.querySelector("i");
  if (pause) {
    icon.classList.add("fa-pause");
    icon.classList.remove("fa-music");
    pause = false;
  } else {
    icon.classList.add("fa-music");
    icon.classList.remove("fa-pause");
    pause = true;
  }
});
```

the second way is that you can use `className`:

```js
document.querySelector("i").className = `fa ${pause ? "fa-pause" : "fa-music"}`;
```